# Pure math courses most relevant towards "computational mathematics"?

Tags: education

Pure math courses most relevant towards "computational mathematics"?

Since I've read that e.g. measure theory has some stuff that's not that applicable to (at least current) computation.

I'm interested in understanding what pure math "courses" are most suited for computation. And what does this depend on really.

Comment: Most pure mathematics topics may have elements not applicable to current computation, but most will also have elements which are applicable. Your question is a little general, as we do not know what form of computation you are looking at or what your choice of pure mathematics courses is.

Comment: @Henry Just in general, not particular to my choices. I'm particularly interested in understanding what makes the difference between "applicable to current computation" and "not applicable to current computation".

Comment: It depends a *lot* on what kind of computation. If you're into solving PDEs numerically, for example, a solid underpinning of PDE theory is essential. And yes, that includes integration theory, Sobolev spaces, and various bits and pieces of functional analysis.

Comment: @HaraldHance-Olsen That's the kind of answer I'm looking for. Although there's more than PDEs.

Comment: But perhaps there are some overarching principles as to "suited for computation". E.g. discretization, regularity, ...?